# Figuring out what SQL wildcards define a set of accounts

Tags: sql, algorithm, filtering, wildcard

We are currently building a complicated financial report where every cell in the table is link to a group of accounts.  Currently we will look at the group of a accounts and we manually figure out the filter/wildcards that defines that group.  We need the filters to only include the accounts in the list.   I was wondering if there a program to do this for us or is there an algorithm we can implement this.  Also, all account numbers will be the same length.

Example:

```
Group A  
10004
10005
10006
21001
21023

Group B
10056
10055

Group C
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
10006
10007
10008
10009
```

Group A would look like `1000[4,5,6], 21001, 21023`

Group B would look like `1005[5,6]`

Group C would look like `1000%`

Comment: What is the output for 10004,10005 and 10023? 100[04,05,23] or 1000[4,5], 10023?

Comment: 100[04,05,23] would be ideal but either way would work.  The main reason we are using filters is group a bunch of a account in just a few rows. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

The general algorithm would be to find the longest prefix starting from the 1-st level(not 0-th level), fix this prefix and then append the different suffixes. Hope you will guess the next steps.

For example

> Group A would look like 1000[4,5,6], 21001, 21023

Trie would look like

[image: prefix tree]

In this case the result is: `1000[4,5,6], 210[01,23]`

Comment: This should work perfectly. Thank You!